# Error "There is no row at position 1" when trying to access next data set of a query ussng C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The search button worked ok the data displayed in the form but when I try to click on the Previous and Next link button I have the error "There is no row at position 1" . Thanks for your help

HTML code

```
<table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style5">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Patient Name"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchSurname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter Patient DOB"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchDOB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="87px" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
```

Form to Display data

```
<table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Hospital Number</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHospitalNumber" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">NHS Number</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNhsNumber" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Partient Surname</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Patient Forename</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtForename" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Patient DOB</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Gender</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGender" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Address</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Height="60px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Post Code</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostcode" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Ethnic Group</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEthnic" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">Registered GP / PCG</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGP" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrevious" runat="server" OnClick="PreviousData" >Previous</asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNextData" runat="server" OnClick="NextData">Next</asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLoadDatabase" runat="server" OnClick="LoadDatabase">Load to Database</asp:LinkButton>
```

C# Code

```
 // display patient details in the form
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd3 = con.CreateCommand();

        cmd3.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM ecamis WHERE 

                                      Surname = @SearchCriteria and DOB=@DOB ";
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchCriteria", txtSearchSurname.Text);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtSearchDOB.Text);

       da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);

        da.Fill(dt);
                i = 0;
               dr = dt.Rows[i];                    
            txtHospitalNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
            txtNhsNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[2]);
            txtSurname.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[3]);
            txtForename.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[4]);
            txtDOB.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[5]);
            txtGender.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[6]);
            txtAddress.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[7]);
            txtPostcode.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[8]);
            txtEthnic.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[9]);
            txtGP.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[10]);

    }
    // search for previous data
    protected void PreviousData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
          Response.Write("First record !");
                lnkPrevious.Enabled = false;
        }

        else
        {
            i--;

    dr = dt.Rows[i]; // Error Here " Additional information: There is no row at position 1."
            txtHospitalNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
            txtNhsNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[2]);
            txtSurname.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[3]);
            txtForename.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[4]);
            txtDOB.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[5]);
            txtGender.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[6]);
            txtAddress.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[7]);
            txtPostcode.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[8]);
            txtEthnic.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[9]);
            txtGP.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[10]); ;
        }             
    }
    // Display next patient data
    protected void NextData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i == (dt.Rows.Count - 1))
        {
            Response.Write("Last record !");
            lnkNextData.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            dr = dt.Rows[i]; // Error Here " Additional information: There is no row at position 1."
            txtHospitalNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
            txtNhsNumber.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[2]);
            txtSurname.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[3]);
            txtForename.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[4]);
            txtDOB.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[5]);
            txtGender.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[6]);
            txtAddress.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[7]);
            txtPostcode.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[8]);
            txtEthnic.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[9]);
            txtGP.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[10]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Slightly off topic but you might want to take a peek at this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: It would appear that your query is returning fewer than 2 records.  And you're trying to access the second record (position 1).

Comment: @David yes the query returning more than 2 record that is why i am using previous or next to display the record

Comment: @EricMbiada: When you debug, what specifically does `dt.Rows` contain when the error happens?  The error isn't *lying* to you... You're trying to access the second element of an array which contains fewer than 2 elements.  Perhaps `dt` is losing its state between postbacks?  You're populating it in a specific event handler, is that event handler being invoked in the request that's failing?

Comment: `dt` and `i` are global variables? You should put a more meaning ful name to `i`

Comment: This code has a several things that make me question what is going on. It looks like you are using class variables to manage the current row and various other elements? You should avoid using select * and only return the columns you need.

Comment: My guess is that when you click your link and the Next or Previous method fires your dataset is empty because the button caused a post back and you are only setting the data in the btnSearch_Click event.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty much telling you everything you need to know; there is no row at position 1, at the time the code came to look in the datatable. Perhaps you have filled the datatable, returned the results to the user after a search, they've clicked some NEXT button, and your code is running again ...

But you're expecting your datatable to still contain the 3 rows it had when the user first searched (upon the last page request), when in fact, it's now empty..

Maybe you declare the DataTable somewhere like at the top of the class file, so it will be instantiated every time a request comes in, but you never make any attempt to store/restore the data inside it; rather, you're expecting the data to be there, surviving across user page navigations, but it won't do that (by design)

Comment: The problem seem to be with index 1

Comment: Brain delay, sorry - i read 1 then forgot and advised as if it was 0

Comment: Another possible cause of this is the query itself is fine but `PreviousData` or `NextData` is called before `btnSearch_Click` is done so the table has not been populated yet. This is a ASP.NET application so a page refresh will reset the state of the page and the table could be emptied.

Comment: @EricMbiada The query returns 3 rows, however if you put a breakpoint on the line `dr = dt.Rows[i]` and you inspect `dt.Rows` with the debugger do you still see all 3 rows there or is the collection empty?

Comment: @Scott Hello scott how can i go round this issue? thanks

Comment: @EricMbiada the way to go around it depends on what the issue is, you need to tell us if `dt` is getting emptied and if previous is being called before search.

Comment: put a breakpoint on `dt.Rows[i];` as other has said debugger doesnt lie. You have an empty Rows array.